# Not getting desired behaviour of translucentstatusbar when navigation drawer is used

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm getting the desired result of translucentstatusbar when I'm not having a navigation drawer in the activity. But when there is a navigation drawer, the status bar doesn't become translucent as desired. I do not have an AppBar or a ToolBar in the activity.

**content_homey.xml**

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/check_internet_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Please check your internet\n connection and try again"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/try_again_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="TRY AGAIN"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/check_internet_text"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.163" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_home_categories"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView
        android:id="@+id/floating_search_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:floatingSearch_close_search_on_keyboard_dismiss="true"
        app:floatingSearch_leftActionMode="showHamburger"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_view_home_categories"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_homey.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_homey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_homey"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_homey_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**nav_header_homey.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**v21/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
     <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

     <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
     <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>

     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

**To**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
     <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

     <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
     <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>

     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

**Apply theme to application in manifest**

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```